# Unable to set the Function property of the PivotField class

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to get the AVERAGE of the "Tempo de Espera" in the PivotTable PT2. However, when I use ".Function = xlAverage" I get the following error: Unable to set the Function property of the PivotField class. Can anybody please give me a hand on this?

```
PT2.AddDataField PT2.PivotFields("Tempo de Espera"), "Count of Tempo de Espera", xlCount


With PT2.PivotFields("Count of Tempo de Espera")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlAverage 'ERROR HERE - ErrorMsg: Unable to set the Function property of the PivotField class
.Caption = "Average of Tempo de Espera"
.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"

End With
```

Comment: Already found the soulution. In order to the above code work, I had to set the  PivotTableVersion to Version15.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In order to the above code work, I had to set the  `PivotTableVersion` to `Version15`.

Took me a full afternoon to get it, but finally worked.
Bellow follows the Code I used when creating PivotTable and PivotCache, which managed to solve the problem:

```
Set PC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
Set PT2 = Sheet4.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PC, TableDestination:=Sheet4.Cells(3, c), _
TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```